# controls in tab are invisible at runtime

Tags: mfc

When I added multiple windows in one tab control of main parent dialogue,it added successfully but whenever I'm run the program that time it runs an application but after pressing the escape button it loses all the controls in child windows, what I do for it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have multiple dialogs associated with the tab control. If so, check out `CDialog::OnCancel` on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw3wtttf(v=vs.80).aspx.